# currentForm as argument or getElementByID?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a bit confused about the advantages/disadvantages (in general) between the two ways .. here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Test </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkLabel(currentForm)
{
//  which method is better?

//  Method 1:
//  var box = document.getElementById("cookiesCB");
//  if(box.checked == false)

//  Method 2:
//  if(currentForm.cookiesCB.checked == false)
    {
        document.getElementById("cookiesLB").style="border: 1px solid red";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com" onsubmit="return checkLabel(this)">
<label id="cookiesLB"> <input type="checkbox" id="cookiesCB"> use cookies </label>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Although both ways are working just fine, I still think there must be some rule or limitation to choose one of them .. any ideas?

Comment: You have to choose the first method when the element you need is not `this`.

Comment: so is the second method always recommended when I can have "this" ?

Comment: Well, yes and no. I don't think there is "recommended" way, but in your situation I would certainly prefer the use of `this`. You have to consider that, for instance, `p` tag does not have direct access to his children, and you have to use the `childNodes` property to access them. I would say that the choice of `this` depends on what you need to do and on the readability of your code with that.

Comment: perfect ... Thanks for clarifying this point for me :)

Comment: You're welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is "recommended" way, but in your situation I would certainly prefer the use of this. You have to consider that, for instance, p tag does not have direct access to his children, and you have to use the childNodes property to access them. I would say that the choice of this depends on what you need to do and on the readability of your code with that. – Marco Luzzara